# Bourne: if statement testing exit status

Tags: shell, if-statement, sh, exitstatus

What is the difference:

```
if IsServerStarted ; then ...
```

and

```
if [ IsServerStarted -eq 0 ] ; then ...
```

Seems to me that these two statements should be equivalent?  Strangely the second statement is always true.

Comment: @skaaffman changed the tag from bourne to bash.  Why?  Isn't Bourne a subset of bash?

Comment: Bourne is an ancient shell from the 1970s nobody uses anymore -- and it is **not** a strict subset of bash (for example, Bourne allows `^` as a pipe character, whereas in modern POSIX shells, bash included, only `|` works). On modern systems, `/bin/sh` is guaranteed to be a shell compliant with POSIX sh, a newer specification heavily influenced by ksh, which is a formerly-commercial shell that took inspiration from Bourne. So there's a long and twisty road back to Bourne from modern shells, but it's not something anyone ever uses today; even 20 years ago, only Solaris still shipped it.

Comment: ...so it's correct to say POSIX sh and bash are "Bourne-family" shells, but they're not actually Bourne-compatible -- not all Bourne code will run on them. (And writing code that behaves correctly with pre-POSIX Bourne also requires a bunch of extra work to deal with bugs in ancient versions of `test`/`[` -- when one gets back into the pre-POSIX world, some of the `"x$foo"` idioms actually have a reason to exist).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following runs the shell function or executable in `$PATH` named `IsServerStarted`, and if its exit code is `0` (i.e. true), runs the `then` branch. If such a function or executable does not exist, the exit code will be non-`0` (i.e. false) and the `then` branch will be skipped.

```
if IsServerStarted ; then ...
```

The following has `[` (aka `test`) check whether `IsServerStarted` is an integer equal to `0`, which (`IsServerStarted` not even containing a single digit) is always **false**. Thus, `[` exits with a non-`0` (i.e. false) code and the `then` branch is always skipped.

```
if [ IsServerStarted -eq 0 ] ; then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the second one will give an error complaining that "IsServerStarted" is not a valid integer. It's considered a string constant so something like

```
var="IsServerStarted"
if [ IsServerStarted == "$var" ] ; then
```

would succeed (or fail if it wasn't equal).

**ndim** is correct regarding the executable or function in the first example you gave.

A couple more variations to consider:

```
if $IsServerStarted ; then ...
```

In that one, the `if` is evaluated based on the return value of a command (executable or function) that is contained in the variable `IsServerStarted`. So you could set `IsServerStarted=true` and then the `if` would succeed since `true` is a shell builtin that always returns true. You could set `IsServerStarted='grep popsicle freezer' and the`if` would pass or fail depending on whether you were out of treats.

```
if [ $IsServerStarted -eq 0 ]; then ...
```

This simply tests whether the variable is equal to zero. If it's not a valid integer it will cause an error message.